# Sanitizing database input in Java without PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, database, sanitization

Is there a reliable way to sanitize database input in Java without using prepared statements?

All the answers I have found suggest using PreparedStatement, but I am trying to avoid the extra round trip to the database server.

-- Additional Info --

- My queries will be very simple and very few will share the same format so there's little performance advantage of any query plan caching.
- The database server will be located on a separate physical location, though still in the same LAN, so there will be extra network bottleneck with the extra round trip required when using prepared statements.

What I'm hoping to find is something like this, which exists in C, Python and PHP:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html

Comment: how about jpa persistence and a DAO?

Comment: Is the extra round trip actually causing a performance issue, or are you just assuming it will?

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood I'm not familiar with them and I'll have a look.

Comment: @DonRoby I'm just assuming it will. I am developing locally and the production servers are not set up yet so can't verify. The queries I'm executing will be quite simple and mostly will not be able to reuse the same query plan from a previous query.

Comment: Check out this. It mentions statment caching the database and in the connection pool.  If you want performance, parepared statements are actaully the way to go. http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365244/Why-Prepared-Statements-are-important-and-how-to-use-them-properly

Comment: My queries will be VERY simple so it is extremely unlikely that query planning would be a bigger bottleneck than a return trip over the network to the database server.

Comment: Network latency is usually in the 0.1-0.3ms range. It wouldn't be an issue unless you're planning to access your database through a WAN, which can be in the 20 ms range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `escapeSql` in the `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`:

```
username="'; or 1=1";
sane_username=StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(username);
// turns into "''; or 1=1"

sql= "select username from users where username = '" + sane_username + "'";
// select username from users where username = '''; 1 or 1'
```

But this is really bad practice.  You should always use prepared statements.

- Saves memory on the sql server
- Allows you to reuse sql statements without a reparsing sql,
  increasing performance
- more secure, you might forget to sanity some input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to avoid using prepared statements for performance reasons. Prep statements can be more efficient if I was to run the same query plan multiple times, which is not the case with this app I'm currently writing.

Comment: FYI @sn00k4h, `escapeSql` provides only string escaping, does not escape special characters, and is no longer available in apache commons for [those](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html) reasons; sabertiger is correct, this is bad practice, use prepared statements since they're database-specific and handle all necessary escaping for the target platform.

Comment: Hi @raffian, what I'm hoping to find is something like this, which exists in C, Python and PHP: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic case of [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).  Yes, `PreparedStatement`s do a little unnecessary work, the same way `ArrayList`s allocate unnecessary memory.  But far and away the benefit of these utilities outweighs their extra costs, and the JIT (or the JDBC driver, in `PreparedStatement`'s case) can improve over time to make them even less expensive.

On the other hand if you re-invent the wheel manually, you're liable to make mistakes, and forever on the hook to ensure this actually remains performant into the future.  Suppose you invest a lot of effort into building a secure alternative to `PreparedStatement`, only to discover next year that a driver update actually renders the `PreparedStatement` call more efficient than your implementation - it's not a far-fetched idea.

Performance concerns are important, but avoid getting hung up on squeezing every last drop out of your application.  Simply doing something that works is likely to be faster, safer, and easier to upgrade in the future than investing large amounts of time into one small aspect of your project.  Put another way, why work around the wonderful benefits `PreparedStatement` offers until you've conclusively decided it's preventing you from improving further?

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel. I'm actually asking if such wheel already exists :) If you imagine you came from a language where both "wheels" exist separately, this wouldn't feel like a premature optimization, but rather using prepared statements simply for its input sanitation purpose would feel like an overkill.

Comment: The problem with "wheels" like `mysql_real_escape_string()` is they're very fragile and prone to failure or error.  Yes, if used correctly you can theoretically gain some slight speed improvements over using `PreparedStatement`, but that's a big if.  `PreparedStatement` provides so much more robust behavior than any string escaping function ever could, that it's hardly even fair to compare them.  Needing sanitized input is more than enough reason to merit `PreparedStatement` over manual escaping.